# Android: VariableDeclaratorId expected. Trying to get screen size

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the screen size in an application, but I am getting the error in my title.

**Syntax error on token "size", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token**

Here is my code:

DisplayMap.java

```
public class DisplayMap extends Activity {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
}
```

Could someone please tell me why I'm getting this error? I've been researching, but I can't figure out what it means.

As always, thank you very much!

Comment: please, read about basic Java lang syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define on method and put all code there and call from the onCreate(..) as it is an activity:

```
public class DisplayMap extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
super.onCreae(b);
getSize();
}
public void getSize() {

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :) I didn't want to use a separate method, but I guess I'll have to.

Comment: U can put this code inside onCreate(...) directly if u dont want another method, just for better code u shud do that.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've read that it's best to not declare a lot of things inside onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

This code should be in a method. Not directly in the class body.